# Ошибка при обновлении pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
C:\programa\Progect\Shablon>pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz
Collecting https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz
  Using cached https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python39\python.exe' 'c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\836D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpuab35mub'
         cwd: C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-klaselhp
    Complete output (34 lines):
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-vpgw8c9h\pyinstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-vpgw8c9h\pyinstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-vpgw8c9h\pyinstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-vpgw8c9h\pyinstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-vpgw8c9h\pyinstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-vpgw8c9h\pyinstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-vpgw8c9h\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-vpgw8c9h\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'pyinstaller-gui.py'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-vpgw8c9h\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-vpgw8c9h\pyinstaller.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz. Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python39\python.exe' 'c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\
pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\836D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpuab35mub' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python39\python.exe' 'c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\836D~1\AppData
\Local\Temp\tmpuab35mub' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pyinstaller` или `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop`

Comment: creating 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-s0hgyqc2\pyinstaller.dist-info'
                                                                                                                                                        
          error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

Comment: WARNING: Discarding (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyinstaller/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python39\python.exe
' 'c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\836D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzp__ic_6' Check the logs for full command output.